# Find how many solutions (counting multiplicity) the equation $\sin z = ez^4$ has on the unit disk $|z|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, rouches-theorem

This is a problem from a past qualifying exam in complex analysis. I'm working through these to study for my own upcoming qual. For this question, I think my proof is fairly straightforward, but I'd like to know whether or not it is correct and complete. I'm also interested in other ways of answer the question. Thanks!

**Problem:**

Find how many solutions (counting multiplicity) the equation $\sin z = ez^4$ has on the unit disk $|z|<1$. Justify your answer.

**My Solution:**

Let $g(z) = \sin(z)$ and $f(z) = -ez^4$ and consider these functions on the unit circle $|z|=1$. We will show by Rouche's Theorem that since $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$, then $f(z)+g(z)$ has the same number of zeros inside the unit circle as $f(z)$ counting multiplicities, thus there are four solutions to the given equation.

First, we need to show that $|\sin(z)|<|e|$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
|\sin(z)| &= \left\vert \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}\right\vert \\
&= \frac{1}{2} |e^{i(x+iy)} - e^{-i(x+iy)}| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}(|e^{i(x+iy)}| + |- e^{-i(x+iy)}|)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(e^{-y} + e^y)
\end{align*}
$$

On $|z|=1$, we have $|y|\leq 1$, thus
$$
|\sin(z)| \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-y} + e^y) \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{1}+e^{-1})< \frac{1}{2}(2e) = e.
$$

Now, we have that when $|z|=1$
$$
|\sin(z)|<e = e|z|^4 = |-ez^4|,
$$

thus $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$, and by Rouche's Theorem, $f(z)+g(z)$ has the same number of zeros inside the unit circle as $f(z)$. Since $f(z) = -ez^4$ is a polynomial, we know by the fundamental theorem of algebra that it has exactly four roots counting multiplicity. Thus,
$$
f(z) + g(z) = \sin(z) - ez^4
$$

has exactly four roots and $\sin(z) = ez^4$ has exactly four solutions. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just one tiny correction I have: if $|y|\leq 1,$ it doesn't follow that $e^{-y}\leq e^{-1};$ rather, its true that $e^{-y}\leq e.$ Note this does not affect your proof at all, which is otherwise seems correct!

Comment: Hmm. I'm concerned that it might actually affect the proof... I need strict inequality here such that $e^{-y} + e^y < 2e$ for $|y| \leq 1$. I know this is true, but I wonder if there's another straightforward way to show this?

Comment: You know it's true for $|y|<1$ and for the cases when $y=\pm 1$ we have that $e+e^{-1}<2e$ so all should be good?

Comment: Ah, yes. True. I was forgetting that $y$ here is just a real number so  $|y|$ just equals $\pm 1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$|g(z)|=|\sin(z)| = |\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}| = |\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{2ie^{iz}}|\leq \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{|e^{2iz}|+1}{|e^{iz}|}\bigg)\\\leq \frac{|e^{2i(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))}|+1}{2|e^{i\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)}|}\leq \frac{|e^{-2\sin(\theta)}\cdot e^{2i\cos(\theta)}|+1}{2\cdot e^{-\sin(\theta)}}\\\leq \frac{(e^{-2\sin(\theta)}+1)}{2\cdot e^{-\sin(\theta)}}\leq \frac{e^{2}+1}{2e}<e$$  where $z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\,0\leq\theta<2\pi$ is an arbitrary point on the unit disc.

After this, what you have done with Rouche's theorem is fine and you can conclude that the number of roots is $4$.